# Reload page in vue just once in mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When user visit the page I want the page to refresh just once.

But if I place `location.reload()` in `mounted()` . It trigger infinity loop page reload

Comment: The lifecycle hooks will restart when the page is reloaded so you need to somehow store it somewhere

Comment: share your code and your condition to reload and stop reloading ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to come up with a way of conditionally reloading the page to avoid the infinite reload.

One way is to set a value in local storage:

```
mounted() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('reloaded')) {
        // The page was just reloaded. Clear the value from local storage
        // so that it will reload the next time this page is visited.
        localStorage.removeItem('reloaded');
    } else {
        // Set a flag so that we know not to reload the page twice.
        localStorage.setItem('reloaded', '1');
        location.reload();
    }
}
```